# JSoup get div#content won't work for me

Tags: android, html, multithreading, webview, jsoup

so I'm trying to get the div tag "content" out of a website (maybe with JSoup..) and I tried this code:

```
public class EcoActivity extends Activity {
    String content1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
System.out.println(content1);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eco);
        WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content1, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    }

private void runThread() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        Document doc;
        public void run() {
            File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
            try{
                doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Element contentElement = doc.select("div#content").first();
            final String content2 = "<html>" + "<head></head>" + "<body>" + doc.getElementById("content").outerHtml() + "</body>" + "</html>";
            final String content = "<html>" + "<head></head>" + "<body>" + /**contentElement.toString() + */"</body>" + "</html>";
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            content1 = content2;
                            System.out.println("Plsrdme " + content2);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

But that doesn't work for me. What did I do wrong, can someone help me out here get this working? I think the problem is, that it can't even get to print it onto the console, or at least I couldn't find it there.
Thanks!

EDIT 1: I found out that content1 just contains the value "null". (In onCreate Block, System.out.println(content1);
And I don't know why...

Comment: you have not assigned any value to content1, you are not calling `runThread()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do it.

Change

`doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html");`

to

`doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html").get();`